# siunitx not matching nontrivial series with fontspec

Tags: xetex, fontspec, siunitx

I am fairly new to XeTeX and Fontspec, but I am trying to use a Google font which has many weights available (Alegreya). I think I am using `\setmainfont` properly to define the various weights as different series and everything seems to work fine. But when I use `siunitx` and the option `detect-all` to match the way the numbers and units are typeset to the context, only some series are correctly identified.

As the example below shows, `siunitx` seems to be indeed attempting to match the series (see the light and bold cases). Yet, also from a quick check of `siunitx.sty`, it seems to me that it only tries to match the first letter of the series and infer a light weight `\lseries` if the series starts with "l" and a bold weight if the series starts with "b". The `banything` series appears to confirm this hypothesis. If this is correct, is there an easy fix to get `siunitx` detect and use the **exact** series?

Here is the example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Alegreya Sans}[
  Ligatures=TeX,
  UprightFont = * Regular,
  ItalicFont = * Italic,
  BoldFont = * Bold,
  BoldItalicFont = * Bold Italic,
  FontFace = {banything}{n}{* Thin},          % just for testing purposes
  FontFace = {banything}{it}{* Thin Italic},  % just for testing purposes
  FontFace = {el}{n}{* Thin},
  FontFace = {el}{it}{* Thin Italic},
  FontFace = {l}{n}{* Light},
  FontFace = {l}{it}{* Light Italic},
  FontFace = {sb}{n}{* Medium},
  FontFace = {sb}{it}{* Medium Italic},
  FontFace = {eb}{n}{* ExtraBold},
  FontFace = {eb}{it}{* ExtraBold Italic},
  FontFace = {ub}{n}{* Black},
  FontFace = {ub}{it}{* Black Italic}
  ]

\DeclareRobustCommand{\elseries}{\fontseries{el}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textel}{\elseries}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\lseries}{\fontseries{l}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textl}{\lseries}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\sbseries}{\fontseries{sb}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textsb}{\sbseries}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\ebseries}{\fontseries{eb}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\texteb}{\ebseries}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\ubseries}{\fontseries{ub}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textub}{\ubseries}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{detect-all}

% just for testing purposes
\DeclareRobustCommand{\banythingseries}{\fontseries{banything}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textbanything}{\banythingseries}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item \textel{This is thin, \textsc{small caps}, and \emph{Italic}: 1 µm and \SI{1}{\um}.}
\item \textl{This is light, \textsc{small caps}, and \emph{Italic}: 1 µm and \SI{1}{\um}.}
\item This is regular, \textsc{small caps}, and \emph{Italic}: 1 µm and \SI{1}{\um}.
\item \textsb{This is medium, \textsc{small caps}, and \emph{Italic}: 1 µm and \SI{1}{\um}.}
\item \textbf{This is bold, \textsc{small caps}, and \emph{Italic}: 1 µm and \SI{1}{\um}.}
\item \texteb{This is extra bold, \textsc{small caps}, and \emph{Italic}: 1 µm and \SI{1}{\um}.}
\item \textub{This is black, \textsc{small caps}, and \emph{Italic}: 1 µm and \SI{1}{\um}.}
\item \textbanything{This is thin but the series in named ``banything'': 1 µm and \SI{1}{\um}.}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

And here the result:

[image: XeTeX Output]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: @Mensch: Thanks!

Comment: I actually got the desired result by a dirty redefining of the font series detection function as ```\cs_new_protected:Npn \__siunitx_detect_font_weight_text: { \cs_set:Npn \__siunitx_font_weight: { \fontseries{\f@series} } }``` inside (a local copy of) ```siunitx```. Certainly, it would have to be replicated for the math mode detector, too. But, alas, I am not sure of potential problems (no \boldmath in case of bold, for instance) and I wonder why ```siunitx``` is not written this way already (there must be a reason, as it is simpler than the existing code).

Comment: you should better stick to the default series values as described in fntguide.pdf. Handling all this series and weight is already complicated enough, even without user inventions. Beside this: siunitx should also work in math, so getting \f@series is often not enough, it also has to decide if this series is bold or not.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer: thanks, the list on p. 5 in fntguide.pdf is exactly what I was missing (and my user inventions were just a by-product of my ignorance).

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer: I changed the example to use the proper (as I understand) series names. But of course the basic issue is still there.